# Jquery: Adding a class to even an odd List-Elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following jquery-code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $ ('ul.image-list li:even').addClass ('even');
        $ ('ul.image-list li:odd').addClass ('odd');
    });
</script>
```

and the following html:

```
<ul class="image-list">
<li>first element</li>
<li>second element</li>
...
<li>last element</li>
</ul>
```

However the jquery does not seem to be applied, because the li-tags don't get the proper classes (even or odd). What am I doing wrong? thanks

Comment: Looks fine to me (and works). Let's see your css.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works just fine for me. Why do you think its not working in your code?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $ ('ul.image-list li:even').addClass('even');
            $ ('ul.image-list li:odd').addClass('odd');
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .even{
            background: gray;
        }
        .odd{
            color:red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="image-list">
    <li>first element</li>
    <li>second element</li>
    <li>third element</li>
    <li>fourth element</li>
    <li>fifth  element</li>
    <li>last element</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can alternatively use:
.filter(":odd").addClass("odd")

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try removing the space between `addClass` and `(`</strike>

Same with `$` and your selector

Are you using Firebug, if you are, look at the HTML, and see if the class names are being applied or not. If they are, you simply forgot to link your stylesheet. If they're not, then there's something wrong with your javascript.

Comment: A space between the function name and parenthesis is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: style-sheet is being applied, but no classes are being applied

Comment: Which means there's a problem with your javascript. Did you remember to reference the jQuery library? Have a look at line 5 in petersendidit's answer.

Comment: do I have to reference it in the <head> section? Or can I put in anywhere in the html?

Comment: the problem might occur because the list is generated by an asp:repeater?

Comment: you need to reference the jquery library before you use `$(document).ready()`. And it should have anything to do with asp:repeater, as that would output the html before jQuery fires.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure you inserted your style sheet into your page? I often forget this.
Second, have you inserted the jquery js file into your page? I forget this very often.
Third, do what peirix says and it should work. I don't see whats wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you create the li dynamically?
In that case the call to add the class should not be on ready() but on a callback after the insertion of the li.

Comment: and how do I add the class on callback?

Comment: and the list is populated with a asp:repeater. However I thought, this would be called "dynamically", or am I wrong?